# How to resolve express server's dependencies after building to dist/

Tags: javascript, node.js, docker, webpack, production-environment

I use webpack to bundle front end assets and put them in a `dist` directory. However I would also like there to be an express server to serve the `index.html` [`html-webpack-plugin`](https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin) generates and also deposits in `dist`. The express server requires a few node modules, mainly express, body-parser, moment, etc.

There is no `node_modules` in `dist` though however, so it falls at the first hurdle when express cannot be found. Should I make a separate package.json just for this little express server and keep it within `dist`, and put its `npm install` on a separate line of my Dockerfile (seems a little complex...) or is there a better way to for this server to resolve its dependencies after webpacking?

*Dockerfile*

```
FROM node:8.4.0-alpine

WORKDIR /opt/app

COPY ./node_modules node_modules 
COPY ./dist . 

EXPOSE 6500

ENTRYPOINT ["node", "server.js"]
```

Line 5 is is a temporary attempt to see if moving all `node_modules` into the app root will allow the server to run. It does but of course this includes everything from express and body-parser, to react and webpack-dev-server.

Comment: Post your Dockerfile so people can have better understanding and visualize the problem

Comment: @TarunLalwani Thanks. Please see update.

Comment: @TarunLalwani Actually I'm not sure I'm following. `server is yours and i can't get inside`. I'm not sure what that means. `Rest I would install webpack inside the container and generate the dist myself.` => This makes sense, use docker to build the app and put it in dist rather than moving it. `Also node_modules using npm install` => not sure what this means. `You can copy a package.json before that` I don't understand why I would do this, or where I would copy it from.

Comment: I re-read my comment and seems like a too casual and bad one. So its gone. Anyways what I meant was that you should install webpack first, then copy the `package.json`, then do a `npm install`, then copy the code and then do a webpack build. Nothing that is installable using commands should come from your host

Answer (score 0):

You are copying npm modules from your local system (most likely) to an alpine instance, which is a different OS which does not necessarily going to be compatible.

You need to run `RUN npm install`.

My guess is you need a dockerfile similar to this:

```
FROM node:8.4.0-alpine

WORKDIR /opt/app

COPY package.json .
RUN npm install

COPY ./dist . 

EXPOSE 6500

//This might also be wrong: ENTRYPOINT ["node", "server.js"]
CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

If I am understanding you correctly you might have to move the files afterwords:

```
RUN mv node_modules dist/node_modules
```

There is a nice tutorial that might be helpful here https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/nodejs-docker-webapp/